# Grant user Contribute on the Site Vs Edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, item-level-permissions

We have a modern team site inside our online tenant >> and we disable members from sharing consent, as follow:-

[image]

so i am trying to figure out what are the differences between having a user with Contribute permission on the site and having Edit permission?
based on my test Contribute can not add new lists/libraries while Edit can...
but the weird thing is that the user with Edit permission can create new list or library but can not modify the permissions for this list/library nor they can define item-level permissions on the list advance setting. So the user with edit permission, can not see those options:-

[image]

+

[image]

So are my observations correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users with the Edit permission level do not have the "Manage Permissions" permission and therefore can not manage site or list permissions.

[image]

Comment: so they can create and even remove the library but they can not manage its permissions ?

Comment: No, they can not.

Comment: can not what create/delete libraries or manage their permisions ?

Comment: They can't manage permissions. As stated in my answer, they don't have the "Manage permissions" permission.

Comment: it is weird that they can create and even remove the library but they can not manage its permissions

Comment: Administrators may be happy for you to create/delete libraries in a site but not comfortable with you giving access to the library you created. Did I answer your original question?